# Есть ли XML погоды на любой день?

Tags: xml

Смысл - написать парсер, который будет добавлять в базу данные погоды на каждый день. Есть ли какой-либо архив xml погоды на каждый день на определенный город?

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите тут: [XML ЭКСПОРТ ПРОГНОЗА ПОГОДЫ](http://www.weather.ua/services/xml/)

UPD: [Вот ещё](http://informer.gismeteo.ru/getcode/xml.php), и [то-же самое](http://www.meteoservice.ru/content/export.html), и ещё [тут есть](http://rp5.ru/docs/xml/ru)

Comment: Не совсем то, ну, вот например, мне нужно узнать, какая была погода, скажем, 25 июня 2010 года. Вот что я имел ввиду.